# Missing builtin rules in my module Boost Build/b2/bjam

Tags: built-in, bjam, boost-build, b2

I am creating a module with name such as `mymodule.jam`. I cannot figure out how to use some [builtin rules](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#bbv2.reference.rules) such as: `constant` or `path-constant`.

I get errors such as:

```
ERROR: rule "path-constant" unknown in module "mymodule".
ERROR: rule "constant" unknown in module "mymodule".
```

What is strange is that it seems I can use these rules without any problem in my `jamroot` or in my `jamfile`s, without seeming to need to `import` anything specific.

Answer (score 0):

These rules are defined in a module named `project-rules` from file `boost-build-1_77_0/tools/build/src/build/project.jam`.

I tried many things, such as:

```
import modules ;
modules.call-in project-rules : path-constant my_TOP_variable : . ;
```

and I got the following error:

`error: Project target requested but not yet assigned for module 'project-rules'.`

so after spending a long time trying many things, my conclusion is that these rules are available only in what the [doc](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#bbv2.tutorial.hierarchy) refers to as "Jamfile" (and not `Jamfile`):

> When we refer to a “Jamfile,” set in normal type, we mean a file called either Jamfile or Jamroot. When we need to be more specific, the filename will be set as “`Jamfile`” or “`Jamroot`.”

because the doc for `constant` says (emphasis mine):

> constant: Sets **project**-wide constant.

So not available in `mymodule.jam` (?).

If you find a solution, please add another answer!

Comment: Maybe that orients toward having a directory `mymodule` with a `jamfile` inside, instead of `mymodule.jam`.